# How to correctly add requestBody in logs in LogRequestFilter?

Tags: java, logging, filtering

I have the following LogRequestFilter in my project:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final String POST = "POST";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@Nonnull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @Nonnull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @Nonnull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        logRequest(wrappedRequest);
        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
    }

    private void logRequest(@Nonnull ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
        if (!log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        log.debug("\n" +
                        "==================== request begin ====================\n" +
                        "URI           : {}\n" +
                        "Method        : {}\n" +
                        "Headers       : {}\n" +
                        "Request Body  : {}\n" +
                        "==================== request end ======================",
                request.getRequestURI(),
                request.getMethod(),
                getHeaders(request),
                getRequestContent(request)
        );
    }

    @Nonnull
    private String getRequestContent(@Nonnull HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            if (POST.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()) && request.getContentType() != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line);
                }
                return content.toString();
            } else {
                return "No request body or content type is null";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error reading request body", e);
            return "Error reading request body";
        }
    }

    @Nonnull
    private Map<String, List<String>> getHeaders(@Nonnull HttpServletRequest request) {
        return Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames())
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        header -> Collections.list(request.getHeaders(header))));
    }
}
```

And I have an error

**Required request body is missing: public**

How can I fix this error and refactor my LogRequestFilter class?

Maybe to check if this is a POST request with a content type (i.e., a request that typically has a request body)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from the Javadoc of `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` is that it only allows you to read the cached contents. It does not make the body re-readable. That means that your logging consumes the entire body, and it's no longer available for the actual request handling.

I think you have two options:

1. Log the request after the filtering. Then the request handling will have read the content, and you can read the cached content from the `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.
2. Don't use `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`. Instead, read the body completely, then replace the request with one that uses the read body. I don't know if there is a class available for that or if you need to write something yourself.

I have written something myself that uses an approach similar to option 2. However, instead of reading the body twice (once for logging, once for actual processing), it reads the body once during processing. When the body stream is completely read there is a callback that performs the logging. That approach does have some caveats - what if the body is never read (GET, DELETE)? What if the body is not completely read (Jackson by default stops parsing once it finds the final `}` or `]`)?

Answer (score 0):

http post can pass json strings, file streams, form-based parameters, etc. You should determine how to use request to obtain parameters based on the value of the request header content-type. Maybe some content-type request parameters are not what you want. For example, when the content-type is application/json, you can use request.getReader() or request.getInputStream() to obtain character and byte streams, but once you do this, you cannot pass request in the actual controller corresponding interface. .getReader() or request.getInputStream() and other methods obtain parameters because these methods are one-time.If you insist on doing this, please refer to the following code.
**obtain content-type:**

```
String contentType = request.getHeader("Content-Type")
```

**obtain json (contentType.equals("application/json")
)**

```
BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader( new 
InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String inputStr;
while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
    responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
//TODO Convert the string to List<Map<String, Object>>, HashMap, etc. according to whether the first character of the character is "{" or "["
```

**obtain params(contentType.equals("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Enumeration enum = request.getParameterNames();
while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
  String paramName = (String) enum.nextElement();
  String paramValue = this.getRequest().getParameter(paramName);
  map.put(paramName, paramValue);
}
```

**obtain file stream(contentType.equals("multipart/form-data"))**
You probably won't need it

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest mRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
MultipartFile file2 = mRequest.getFile("myFile");
InputStream inputStream = file2.getInputStream()
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the actual issue - the fact that the body has already been consumed when the processing starts.